# Can __shared__ variables be encapsulated in __device__ __host__ functions?

Tags: cuda, c-preprocessor, gpu-shared-memory

I would like to encapsulate the following CUDA code:

```
__device__ __host__ 
void myFunction()
{
#ifdef __CUDA_ARCH__
    __shared__ float sharedVar[3];
#else
    float sharedVar[3];
#endif

    ...
}
```

into something more streamlined such as:

```
__device__ __host__ 
void myFunction()
{
    SHARED_MEMORY float sharedVar[3];
    ...
}
```

Where `SHARED_MEMORY` evaluates to `__shared__` if `__CUDA_ARCH__` is defined, or nothing otherwise.  The following is the obvious approach:

```
#define SHARED_MEMORY \
#ifdef __CUDA_ARCH__ \
    __shared__ \
#endif
```

However, this doesn't compile because other C-preprocessor directives can not be used in a macro.  Is there any way to encapsulate this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was move the `#ifdef` outside of the `#define`, doh!

```
#ifdef __CUDA_ARCH__
#define SHARED_MEMORY __shared__
#else
#define SHARED_MEMORY
#endif
```